# Get angle between two transforms in a single plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two game objects in a scene.

I'm aware that I can use the .angle function to get the angle between the two objects, however this is a single angle in 3d. What I want is to get two different angles, one in the vertical plane and one in the horizontal plane.

So, if I had one gameObject, and another 20 degrees up and 30 degrees to the right, I would like to get:

Vertical = 20;
Horizontal = 30;

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to project the vectors onto the vertical and horizontal plane respectively and the calculate the angles.

I use the direction between two objects, t1 and t2, and t1.forward to calculate the angle. This way if you rotate the t1 the angle will change but not if you rotate t2.

In this example t1 is the object you want to calculate from, like the camera, and t2 is the position you measures against, like the goal.

```
void Update () 
{
    Debug.Log(AngleInPlane(t1, t2.position, Vector3.up));
    Debug.Log(AngleInPlane(t1, t2.position, Vector3.right));
}

public float AngleInPlane(Transform from, Vector3 to, Vector3 planeNormal)
{
    Vector3 dir = to - from.position;

    Vector3 p1 = Project(dir, planeNormal);
    Vector3 p2 = Project(from.forward, planeNormal);

    return Vector3.Angle(p1, p2);
}

public Vector3 Project(Vector3 v, Vector3 onto)
{
    return v - (Vector3.Dot(v, onto) / Vector3.Dot(onto, onto)) * onto;
}
```